# How to concatenate two rows of a table in sql query?

Tags: mysql, yii1.x

in my `employees` table i have three fields `first_name`, `last_name`, `middle_name`. I used an csqldataprovider as follows. I want to display an employee's fullname. ie, first_name+last_name+middle_name. so i tried like this employees.concat(first_name,last_name,middle_name) it gave me an error that no field is there named concat in employees.

```
$sql    =   "SELECT employee_tasks.task_name as Task, employee_task_log.log as Log,
                            employees.first_name as Name, employee_task_log.id as Id
                    From employee_task_log 
                    Left join employee_tasks ON employee_tasks.id=employee_task_log.task_id 
                    Left join employees ON employees.id=employee_task_log.employee_id 
                    where employee_tasks.id ={$id} " ;

        $dataProvider   =   new CSqlDataProvider( $sql, array( 'keyField' => 'Id', 'pagination'=>false  ) );
```

how can i concat the `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[CONCAT_WS](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php)**:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name);
```

So the query would be:

```
SELECT employee_tasks.task_name as Task, employee_task_log.log as Log,
CONCAT_WS(' ', employees.first_name, employees.middle_name, employees.last_name) as Name,
employee_task_log.id as Id
From employee_task_log 
Left join employee_tasks ON employee_tasks.id=employee_task_log.task_id 
Left join employees ON employees.id=employee_task_log.employee_id 
where employee_tasks.id ={$id}
```

Comment: it gave me an error FUNCTION employees.CONCAT_WS does not exist

Comment: who told you to use `employees.CONCAT_WS` use only `CONCAT_WS`

Comment: i wrote query.. just give a try